# React hooks not working in gatsby productioin build

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby. I'm trying to build an application and at some point I just need to use a react hook - useState and useEffect. While it works fine for me when serving the site locally, the functionality does not work after building the project. Generally, I try to add onMouseLeave and onMouseEnter actions to each item in the menu and then manipulate individual items. In production build it looks as if Javascript is not supported. I understand that when building I can't access the window and document objects, but I don't use it at all. I even tried to display a simple console log in useEffect - nothing logs in the console.

I tried to do something like this - it works locally. Once built, the logic does not run.

```
<ul>
    {links.map((link) => {
        return <li id={link.id} onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredElement(link.id)} onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredElement(undefined)}>
            <Link to={link.path} aria-haspopup={!!link.items} aria-expanded={hoveredElement === link.id}>
                {link.title}
            </Link>
            {link.items && <HeaderSubMenu {...link} />}
        </li>;
    })}
</ul>
```

could someone explain this case? Is this the default behavior in gatsby or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) attribute.

```
<ul>
    {links.map((link) => {
        return <li key={link.id} id={link.id} onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredElement(link.id)} onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredElement(undefined)}>
            <Link to={link.path} aria-haspopup={!!link.items} aria-expanded={hoveredElement === link.id}>
                {link.title}
            </Link>
            {link.items && <HeaderSubMenu {...link} />}
        </li>;
    })}
</ul>
```

If even adding the `key`, your code doesn't work, try adding a CodeSandbox since it's difficult what could go wrong just with the provided code.